# C# convert Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.FieldUserValue to Microsoft.Sharepoint.Cliend.User

Tags: c#, sharepoint

Ok i am using a Caml Query to retrieve a item from a sharepoint list. I get the item loop through the field values to the one i want. My problem is i need to convert that which is a FieldUserValue Datatype to a normal User datatype. There is a method to retrieve FieldUserValue from User but not the other way around...

```
 User Usr;


        foreach (ListItem item in items)
        {
            foreach (var f in item.FieldValues)
            {
                if (f.Key == "ColumnTitleofDataTypePersonorGroup")
                {
                    //Error Message
                    Usr = f.Value;
                }
            }

        }
```

The Detailed ErrorMessages says
Error   2   Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.User'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
I think I am just missing something obvious..
Thanks for any help in advance..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following example demonstrates how to get [User object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.user.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) from [FieldUserValue object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.fielduservalue.aspx):

```
var list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
var item = list.GetItemById(itemId);
ctx.Load(item);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();

var author = (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldUserValue) item["Author"];
var authorUser = ctx.Web.SiteUsers.GetById(author.LookupId);
ctx.Load(authorUser);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: Could you please help me with this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53893774/how-to-manage-client-context-object-in-seperate-class-library